# How to insert float variable in database properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, number-formatting

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment_data` (
  `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDesc` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `orderAmount` float NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `orderid` (`orderid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and I'm trying to insert a line in it using PHP.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO payment_data '.
           '(orderid, orderDesc, name, email, orderAmount) '.
           'VALUES ( '.$form_order_id.', "'.$form_order_desc.'", "'.$form_name.'", "'.$form_email.'", '.number_format($form_order_amount, 2, '.', ',').' )';
```

The problem is that "orderAmount" is inserted without the decimal part. For example if $form_order_amount=30,45 then 30 is what's inserted in database.

I used number_format() because it's supposed to convert "30,45" to "30.45".

Comment: You need the decimal precision for float `orderAmount` float(7,2)` or something desireable

Comment: `30,45` with a `,` decimal is not a valid number to a computer; you need a decimal point (`.`) when inserting to MySQL

Comment: That said, don't use `float` for database money, use [decimal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).... or even better, adjust the value to cents so you're working with integers if you ever need to do adjustments for tax calculations, etc where floating point precision may cause issues

Comment: number_format() should be used when ___displaying___ a float value, not internally when storing it, and it won't convert `30,45` to `30.45`, but will do the reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert form_order_amount to float first, using this:

```
$form_order_amount = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $form_order_amount));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This is how I did it. Source php [manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

```
public static function tofloat($num) {
    $dotPos = strrpos($num, '.');
    $commaPos = strrpos($num, ',');
    $sep = (($dotPos > $commaPos) && $dotPos) ? $dotPos :
            ((($commaPos > $dotPos) && $commaPos) ? $commaPos : false);

    if (!$sep) {
        return floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $num));
    }

    return floatval(
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, $sep)) . '.' .
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, $sep + 1, 
        strlen($num)))
    );
}
```