# MySQL inserts int instead of doubles

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a row "duration" of type `double` (I also tried decimal and float with same result).

When I now insert a row with:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_mytable`(<...>, `duration`) VALUES (<...>, 0.5)
```

everything is entered correctly but instead of `0.5` I get `0`. And if I use `1.5` I get `1` and so on.

The same happens when I edit the row manually and enter `0.5` as value for that row.

I tried entering `'0.5'` instead of `0.5` and since I'm from Germany I also tried using a comma instead of a period, but that had the same effect.

How do I have to enter it?

Comment: Is the duration column of type double?

Comment: didn't i said that i my first sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert float variable in database properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137364/how-to-insert-float-variable-in-database-properly)

Comment: @Stony the linked post is a php question where the solution was to replay , with . but as i said i tried both and i'm inserting the mysql command directly in the phpmyAdmin plattform

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your case and created a test table with a float and double field. And have inserted 0.5 to the table. With phpmyadmin you get the following query.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`test`, `id`) VALUES ('0.5', NULL);
```

and it's working. When i run the query directly it's working in the same way and i get the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it working by deleting the column and adding it as a new one. Don't know what the problem was, but thanks anyway